# is Recurring Event of kendo scheduler is possible on context menu of scheduler with angular 7?

Tags: kendo-ui, angular7, contextmenu, kendo-scheduler, recurring-events

as i tried Recurring event in my kendo scheduler and it's working fine on double click but not working when calling on context menu of kendo scheduler

i need to open it with modified fields with it on context menu of kendo scheduler with angular 7

here is my context menu
and I want to trigger a recurrence event on click onSelectMenu($event)

```
  <kendo-contextmenu [target]="target" [items]="items" (popupOpen)="onPopupOpen($event)" (select)="onSelectMenu($event)">
    <ng-template kendoMenuItemTemplate let-item="item">
      <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-contextmenu>
```

so is this possible with angular7?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.